# Where can I find Armory 92.3 for download?

Tags: armory, windows, installation

I am trying to use Windows XP and need Armory 92.3 
to do it. Where can I download that version without compiling?

Answer (score 2):

A version for XP can be downloaded from [github](https://github.com/goatpig/BitcoinArmory/releases/download/v0.93.3/armory_0.93.3_winall.exe). This is actually 93.3 not 92.3. It says *"Armory 0.93.3 for Windows XP, Vista, 7, 8+ (64-bit)"*

I have not used this version and cannot vouch for it in any way.

As I expect you know, Windows-XP is an insecure operating system. [Microsoft stopped supporting XP in 2014](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/windows/end-of-windows-xp-support), 5 years ago now. Personally I'd install Linux (e.g. Ubuntu) on the same hardware in order to create a safer environment than XP for a Bitcoin wallet. This might be slightly less of an issue if the computer is never connected to the Internet or to USB devices etc. Duubtless you have considered this but I feel I should mention this for any less-informed people who might read this.